# How to swich between NavBar Tabs without bottom in R Shin

Tags: r, shinydashboard

I am creating a dashboard with multiple tabs in R shiny, it is possible that after a certain time, the dashboard will automatically switch from table 1 to tab 2 without the need for a button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a fully working example.

1. The timer is set to 10 seconds. You can see the remaining time before switching to tab 2 ([source for this part here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49254510/13241545)).
2. After the time has elapsed the first `observe` uses `updateTabsetPanel` to switch the tab. The timer is "stopped" (in this case simply ignored).
3. If a user switches tabs manually, the timer will be stopped by the second `observe`.

This solution uses a `shiny::tabsetPanel` ([more](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tabsets.html)). If you prefer `shinydashboard::tabItems` you have to use `updateTabItems` instead of `updateTabsetPanel`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  # App title ----
  titlePanel("Auto Tabsets"),
  
  # Sidebar layout with input and output definitions ----
  sidebarLayout(
    
    # Sidebar panel for inputs ----
    sidebarPanel(
    ),
    
    # Main panel for displaying outputs ----
    mainPanel(
      
      # Output: Tabset w/ plot, summary, and table ----
      tabsetPanel(id = "inTabset", type = "tabs",
                  tabPanel("Tab 1", verbatimTextOutput("timeleft")),
                  tabPanel("Tab 2", verbatimTextOutput("data"))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Initialize the timer, 10 seconds, active.
  timer <- reactiveVal(10) # in seconds
  active <- reactiveVal(TRUE)
  
  
  # Output the time left and timer status on tab 1
  output$timeleft <- renderText({
    paste("Time left: ", timer(), " - Timer ", ifelse(active(), "On", "Off"))
  })
  
  # Output the time left and timer status on tab 2
  output$data <- renderText({
    paste("Time left: ", timer(), " - Timer ", ifelse(active(), "On", "Off"))
  })
  
  
  
  # TIMER
  # observer that invalidates every second. If timer is active, decrease by one.
  observe({
    invalidateLater(1000, session)
    isolate({
      if(active())
      {
        timer(timer()-1)
        if(timer() < 1)
        {
          active(FALSE)
          updateTabsetPanel(session, "inTabset", selected = "Tab 2")
        }
      }
    })
  })
  
  
  # TABSET
  # Stop the timer if the user changes the tab manually
  observe({
    if (input$inTabset != "Tab 1")
      isolate(active(FALSE))
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 0):

shinyDashboards has a function called `updateTabItems`

Use that in the server to update based on whichever event triggers it.